# Why does range throw an identifier error in Racket?

Tags: list, lisp, range, racket

I am using Racket and my file looks like

```
#lang racket
(range 10)
```

But when I evaluate `(range 10)` I receive

```
Error: struct:exn:fail:contract:variable

reference to an identifier before its definition: range in module:
```

and then it lists `/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/main.rkt`.

I am using Geiser and Emacs to evaluate - am I missing a library?

Comment: `range` is defined in modules `racket/list` and `racket` so it should work. You might want to try running it in either `DrRacket` or `racket <file>` in terminal to verify that your racket installation is good.

Comment: What version of Racket are you running? it might be that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `range` function was added in Racket 5.3. If you have a version older than that, it won't work.